# Why do i get extra undefined in last row of my output?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function triangle1(n , shape){
    let ajib =[];
    for (let row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        let b ="";
        let a="";
        
        for (let space = 1; space <= n - row; space++) {
            b= b + " ";
        }
    
    
        for (let star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            a = a + shape + " "; ///" " will make an Equilateral triangle 
        }
       
        let c = b + a;
        
        console.log(c);

        ajib.push(c);
        //return c ;

    
    }
    
    console.log(ajib)
   

}
console.log(triangle1(5,"a"))
```

This is my the output:

```
    a 
   a a 
  a a a 
 a a a a 
a a a a a 
[ '    a ', '   a a ', '  a a a ', ' a a a a ', 'a a a a a ' ]
undefined
```

First: i do not know where this **undefined** thing come from!

How can i get rid of it?

Second: when i use  `return c;`  instead of  `console.log(c)` to output each row i get a wrong result like :

```
    a
```

Why does this happen and how can i solve it?

Comment: Indexes usually start with zero. Are you overrunning your array length by starting with 1 in your `for` statement?

Comment: The `undefined` is the return from `triangle1()` which is indeed not defined. You can *get rid* of it by calling `triangle1(5,"a")` instead of `console.log(triangle1(5,"a"))`.

Comment: I think the undefined is something expected. Are you developing on a site like repl? The weird a result seems to be because you log the letter before and then you do an early return, causing that the console.log(ajib) is never called.

Comment: I suggest using a `debugger` statement and debug the code - it should become obvious where the `undefined` is being logged

Comment: @Lain you suggested a good way but now when i use  ````return c  ```` instead of ````console.log(c)```` in my function the triangle will not be shown as it was!

Comment: It seems like you are not really aware of what you are outputting. Returning a value in a function and logging some values in the console are totally different topics. What you probably wanna do, taking your original code, is: 1. Remove `console.log(c);`. 2. Replace `console.log(ajib)` with `return ajib.join('\n')`. 3. Replace `let ajib =[];` with `let ajib =[''];`. 4. Leave `console.log(triangle1(5,"a"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its from `console.log(triangle1(5,"a"))` because triangle has no return value. It correctly prints the letters while running the function, then undefined since the return value of triangle is undefined
Second: when you use `return c` you are ending the function immediately. Add it to a list and return the list

Answer (score 0):

See comments and explanations in the following snippet.

```js
function triangle1(n, shape){
    //REM: You might wanna add an empty entry, so the console.log always creates a new line - to align the pyramid properly.
    let ajib = [''];

    //REM: If you enter more than one letter as shape, you need to multiply whitespaces by its length
    let whitespace = ' '.repeat(shape.length);

    for (let row = 1; row <= n; row++){
        let b = '';
        let a = '';
     
        for (let space = 1; space <= n - row; space++) {
            b= b + whitespace;
        };
    
        for (let star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            a = a + shape + whitespace; ///" " will make an Equilateral triangle 
        };
       
    //REM: You do not really need c, since you can just push the result to ajib
        //let c = b + a;

        ajib.push(b + a)

        //REM: Here is the wrong point to return c, since it leaves the function and only returns c from this iteration - always the first in this case
        //return c ;
    };
    
    //REM: You should output the whole list. To reuse and log as see fit
    return ajib
};

//REM: Adding the event
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let tValue = triangle1(
      Number(document.querySelector('input[type=number]').value) || 1,
      document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value || 'a'
    );
    
    console.log(tValue.join('\n'))
})
```

```html
<input type = 'number' value = '5'>
<input type = 'text' value = 'a'>
<input type = 'button' value = 'click me'>
```